# Optimization of for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I'm trying to optimize for-loop in my R-code. 
Summary:
I've a data table with 47 million rows and 4 columns( designated by 'nvars' in code). 
I want to compare row-wise values in each column and if any two are equal, set delete flag as 1, else 0.

I need to delete all those rows in which at least two values in any of 4 columns are equal. (values are numeric in all columns, e.g. 1,2,3... )

I tried optimising using vectorisation but it's still taking ~1.5 hours (approx.)

Can this be optimised further?

```
test2 <- as.data.table(test2)
delete_output <- numeric(nrow(test2))
for (i in 1:nrow(test2)){
  for (j in 1:(nvars-1)){
    k=j+1
    if (test2[i,..j] == test2[i,..k]){
      delete_output[i] <- 1
     next
   } 
  }
 }
```

If any two values in a particular row are equal, it should assign delete flag as 1.

My file should look like the one in the image. This is an example of 3 input variable and corresponding output variable (delete). Check that if all V1, V2, V3 are unique for a particular row, delete flag is equal to 0, else 1.

[image: Input file]

Comment: Can you provide a test dataset? For example a subset of your data.

Comment: `test2[apply(test2, 1, function(x) all(table(x)==1)), ]`

Comment: @jogo If I'm not wrong, this will work if all values are equal to 1. I should have posted input file earlier. Can you please check if your solution will work on the input data I provided?

Comment: @Ashu Please use the output from `dput(...)` to show your data. Do you need the additional column? The logic in my code is to select only those rows, in which all elements are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` (but I fear it might not be fast enough) and check for `any` `duplicated` value.

```
df$delete <- +(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(duplicated(x))))

df
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 delete
#1   3  3  3  1      1
#2   1  4  4  3      1
#3   2  2  1  4      1
#4   2  2  3  3      1
#5   2  4  4  2      1
#6   1  3  2  4      0
#7   1  1  1  3      1
#8   4  2  1  1      1
#9   3  4  2  2      1
#10  1  2  2  4      1
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1432)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
```

Comment: Awesome!! This worked like a charm!! Didn't take more than 2 mins on all my data( 47 million rows).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
set.seed(1432)
test2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
test2
test2[apply(test2, 1, function(x) all(table(x)==1)), ]
```

This will select only those rows, in which all elements are unique.
If you need the extra column you can do:

```
set.seed(1432)
test2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
test2
test2$delete <- !apply(test2, 1, function(x) all(table(x)==1))
test2
```